# Python, manipulating nd.arrays: merge, replace data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 3 numpy.ndarray named `vertices`, `bcoords` and `tet`, with the following `shape`:

```
vertices    (1965, 4, 6) 
tet         (1048576,)    
bcoords     (1048576, 4)
```

I want to access the data in the ndarrays to make some operations.

_

`tet` contains numbers (indices) that refer to the values in `vertices`

the sequences of values in `tet` and `bcoords` are the same

---

EDIT2:

```
vertices    (1965, 4, 6)
```

the values in `vertices` are `1965` simplices, defined by `4` points, each `point` being defined by `6` values `R, G, B, X, Y, Z`

The simplices were computed using Delaunay triangulation of the `X, Y, Z` coordinates of each `point`

```
tet         (1048576,)    
bcoords     (1048576, 4)
```

The values in `tet` are indices of simplices. They were made with a list of `1048576` `target` (structure: `X, Y, Z`). A `target` might or might not be contained by one of the simplices.

If the target is in a simplex, tet contains one of the 1965 indices, if not, `tet` contains the value `-1`

The values in `bcoords` are the barycentric coordinates of the list of `target`

---

I'd like to make a loop through `tet` or `bcoords` (or better through the two at the same time) that will give me `vertices` (i.e. if `tet` returns `10` I want to get the 10th value of the array `vertices`), and at the same time I'd like to get the 4 corresponding values in `bcoords`

---

EDIT:

I wrote *"if `tet` returns `10` I want to get the 10th value of the array `vertices`"*

I meant the 10th `row` of `vertices`, the data it contains, here are some samples:

`print tet` gives:

```
[1758 1758 1758 ...,   33   33   33]
```

a list of indices

`print vertices[1758]` gives:

```
[[ 63.           0.          63.           4.56112396   3.97230907
    5.22919258]
 [  0.           0.          95.           4.05451235   4.07627874
    7.38992147]
 [ 63.           0.           0.           5.91857152   5.28300682
    4.5745692 ]
 [  0.          63.          63.           4.20672279   5.43250873
    6.32627709]]
```

a list of 4 points

---

How can I do that?

- Should I merge `tet` and `bcoords`? And if yes, how can I do that?

  Or is there any way to loop through the 2 arrays at the same time?
- How can I replace the values of `tet` (that are indices of the values in `vertices`) by the values contained in `vertices`?
- Is this one of the reasons why `Pandas` exists, and if yes, how to use it in this particular case?

Thanks

Comment: You should explain how the numbers in `tet` index into `vertices`. you say  _if tet returns 10 I want to get the 10th value of the array vertices_ but is is not clear what the 10th value of a 3 dimensional array means.

Comment: @DanielMahler Thank you, I added an EDIT to clarify your point

Comment: What are the values in tet, what are the values in vertices, and what are the values in vertices? There's no clear way that they go together, and just printing out the numbers is not extremely helpful.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Hi, I added an EDIT2 to answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory, just use fancy indexing:

```
mask = tet != -1
tet2 = tet[mask]
bcoords2 = bcoords[mask, :]
vertices2 = vertices[tet2]
```